# How to decode barcode USPS 4 state format

Tags: java, android, zxing

i have a this question about a work that i should do for a client and i can't find any free lib to decode barcode USPS 4 state format and i finally I'm here hoping you can help me to find a solution 
for the first step make all necessary research and after 5 days I'm here i you know anyone or can give me and advice you are welcome.
**zxing-barcode library**  can't decode it so i want to know if i will have to write a decoder or if there are other solution in my case and thank you for your responses.

Comment: You'll have to make or buy a decoder. The USPS 4 state postal code format isn't like 'regular' 1-D barcodes like UPC/EAN with start/stop indicators and is specific to postal applications. As you may have noticed the 4 state format has tighter tolerances for visual alignment than 1-D barcodes, which hints at its legacy OCR postal equipment origins.

Comment: thank you and if i have to write a decoder myself so do you have any suggestion for me please I've made  lot of research and found nothing about this topic for now and i really want it so if i can find any topic o tuto about how it's work so i think i can find my way

Comment: You might want to explain in what context you are trying to decode a 4-state postal code (which is for envelopes sliding through a OCR reader so the position is more known). If you are trying with a camera, you'll have to find the clock row and you'll have a better chance of finding it by restricting where you'll be decoding rather than anywhere in the field of view.

Comment: the 4-state barcodes use 4 different types of bar, RAW data will always be a sequence of numbers in range of 0-3.
Tracker (smallest middle bar) is 0
Ascender (upper bar) is 1
Descender (lower bar) is 2
Full-bar (longest one) is 3
i just want to get the specific value for each bar it's all that i need.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. The spec is available at the first reference link in the [Wikipedia page for Intelligent Mail barcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Mail_barcode). You can easily find code online to generate the postal code. My prior comment was to a possible method of resolving where in an image is the postal code by looking for the 'center clock' and then checking at right angles for ascender & descenders (and perhaps do some image processing to increase contrast). As I said earlier, 4 state isn't a 1D barcode designed for lasers or 2D designed for camera. Good luck